# Laravel query builder join where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I've got this query:

```
$query = QueryBuilder::for(Advertisement::class)
            ->with('locations');
```

The locations method on Advertisement looks like this:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class, 'advertisement_locations', 'advertisement_id', 'location_id');
}
```

So a advertisements `belongsToMany` locations in between is a pivot table called `advertisement_locations`.

Now I would only get the advertisements between a given `long` and `latitude` that's on the `locations` table.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$query = Advertisement::whereHas('locations', function($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('long', [$min, $max])
        ->whereBetween('latitude', [$min, $max]);
});
```